# Trouble with auto refresh in table

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have this `index.php` file to show some stuff in tables from loop:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM usertbl';
$stmt = $hund->runQuery($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

<?php foreach ($row as $runloop) { ?>
<table><th> <?php echo $runloop['id']; ?> </th></table>
<?php } ?>
```

However, I wish to have auto refresh for those tables. So I have this new file `data.php` and a updated `index.php`:

data.php:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM usertbl';
$stmt = $hund->runQuery($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
```

index.php:

```
   <div id="show"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#show').load('data.php')
        }, 3000);
    });
   </script>

   <?php foreach ($row as $runloop) { ?>
   <table><th> <?php echo $runloop['id']; </th></table>
   <?php } ?>
```

This will refresh and print the output in the above `<div>`:

```
<div class="show"></div>
```

And it works great, but I don't really have any clue how to put that inside the loop for the tables, just as the first `index.php` file. Any suggestions of a direction to take in this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to call `data.php` and return the response in json format for a better approach

Try:
**js**

```
function populate(){
var items= [];
$.ajax({
 url: 'data.php',
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data){

    //do something with data here
      console.log(data);
    //loop through data and push to array
    $.each(data, function(i,v){
       items.push('< th >'+v+'< /th >');
    });       
    //join array and append to table
    $('#sampleTable tbody').html(items.join(','));
    },
 error: function(err){
     console.log(err.responseText);
    }
});
}

//call populate every 10 secs (example only , you can change to how many    seconds you like)
setTimeout(function(){
  populate();
},10000);
```

**data.php**

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM usertbl';
$stmt = $hund->runQuery($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: it looks like something that is very useful! however I have a bit trouble accessing the response json format. The id of table should be 'sampleTable tbody' I guess. I am pretty new in ajax and in scripts generally...

Comment: yes, correct. I just made it for sample purposes only. Make your own table in the html and name the id whatever you like.

Comment: But how to pull out the json ?

Comment: It's already there in `success` callback of the ajax. When the request is successful then the `data`  passed to it will be usable already.

Comment: I thank you already. But is it possible you can give me a little html example ? Can save me a lot of google time:)

Comment: using the posted answer above, make a table in the `html` and call the `populate()` function in the javascript. You should see something in the console when you go to Inspect element

Comment: here's a sample from the web that might help you understand jquery ajax - https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/aPMJF/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116775/discussion-between-hans-pede-and-graceth).

Answer (score 1):

In this line you forgot to close `<?php` ...

Possibly that's why `foreach` loop doesn't work correctly

```
     <?php foreach ($row as $runloop) { ?>
   <table><th> <?php echo $runloop['id']; ?></th></table>
   <?php } ?>
```

Put these lines in `data.php` where `print_r()` is.

Comment: thanks for feedback and that is right, - I edited the line now. This just serve as a simplified illustrative example. The table is relatively huge and there is more columns than just 'id', so it troubles me

Comment: What problem you get?

Comment: The problem is, that I actually get a great (big) array from the `print_r()` in the `<div>`. But I dont know how to pass each single value into the table loop since I cannot threat the `<div>` as a array right ? If I do as you suggest I just split the array up in multiple arrays which is not my goal

Comment: can you show me a quick demo array as your array and what you want to do with that array?

Comment: I think I go with the above from graceth, but now I got new problems:)